# Is there a way to "make" Kethane?

Tags: mods, kerbal-space-program

I'm still trying to learn how things work in the Kethane mod, and I'm having a bit of a hard time with it since my current game doesn't appear to have any Kethane available at the KSC launch pad. I'm pretty sure I've played a game where there was, but that was a couple saves and re-installs ago.

Having Kethane available at the KSC launch pad would be really handy so I can test my mining/conversion craft before I commit them to an actual mission. Is there another mod I can use, or a file I could manually edit, to put Kethane where I want it?

Comment: Is teleporting your craft to an existing Kethane Depot an option?

Comment: @jazzpi I'm not always just looking to stock up on Kethane. I sometimes need to test mining capabilities as well. If there's a "safe" (i.e.: not going to corrupt my save) method to teleport to a location known to have Kethane below the surface, that might be a useful alternative.

Answer (score 3):

As you've said you can also teleport to a known Kethane location, you could use [HyperEdit](http://www.kerbaltekaerospace.com/)'s *Ship Lander* feature to land at a known Kethane location.

First, put your ship/base into orbit (otherwise, it will break up on landing). You can also use HyperEdit's *Orbit Editor* to do that: Press Alt+H, then click on "Orbit Editor" and enter 100000 as altitude, then click on "Set".

Then, find a Kethane location on Kerbin, where the center of the hexagon is on land. Hover your mouse over the hexagon. You will see the coordinates of the center. Open the *Ship Lander* and enter the coordinates.
Your latitude is the N/S coordinate. If it is a N coordinate, just enter the number. If it is a S coordinate, enter the negative of the number. (i.e. 2.5N turns to 2.5, 36.21S turns to -36.21)

Same goes for the longitude: E coordinates are positive, W coordinates are negative.

Now, click the "Land/Drop" button **once**. Note that you must not be in Time Warp. You now fall gently down to the ground and can rotate your spacecraft to match the ground. If the ground isn't level enough, press "Land/Drop" again **once**. Then quickly Press the "Set" button in the *Orbit Editor* again (assuming altitude is still at 100000) to put yourself in orbit again. You can then choose a new site. If you find you don't have enough time to rotate your craft, put yourself in orbit again (same procedure as for non-level ground) and set the "Alt" in the *Ship Lander* to something higher and land again.

Comment: Interesting tool, but I'm having some problems getting there in one piece. Other times, it gets me very much *not* there - I've made a few water landings that definitely shouldn't have been.  And, interestingly, the Kethane doesn't seem to be where my last scans say it should be.

Comment: Nevermind. I think the issue was I was forgetting to put negative for S/W.

Answer (score 0):

As often, the Dark Side™ offers a solution for people without conscience. The [KE-WAITNONOSTOP-01 Kerbal Unreconstitutionator](http://forum.kerbalspaceprogram.com/threads/53478-Kethane-What-is-the-KE-WAITNONOSTOP-01-Kerbal-Unreconstitutionator) provides 150 units of Kethane *[from a readily available and fully renewable resource](https://github.com/Majiir/Kethane/blob/master/Parts/kethane_kerbalBlender/part.cfg)*.

Comment: This doesn't allow you to test your mining craft though, does it? Unless you have some **evil** design for your mining stations...

Comment: That way you get enough kethane to test the KE-J65 Zero-Bypass Turbine which currently seems to be the only engine running on kethane directly. You can test the mining equipment in a dry run - if the drill makes it into the soil, you probably can suck the kethan out of it. The zero-bypass turbine was the only thing making me wish to get filled kethane tanks.

Comment: This solves the problem of not having Kethane in the tank, which is useful for testing conversion and other processes. However, it does not solve the issue of not having any Kethane in the ground which is needed to test more humane mining functions.